# Excel using 2 cells in an if statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column B has different operating systems, Column C has the amount of days B has been offline. I would like to have if B contains "server" and C > 1 then D fills with "Attention"

```
=IF(B:B,"*server"),=IF(C:C,">1"),"Attention")
```

If B has anything that does not contain "server" like Windows 10, or Linux in it then D should remain empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in D1 and copy down:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SERVER",B1)),C1>1),"Attention","")
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that B doesn't just have the Work "server" it can have "Server 2012", "Server 2003" etc. That is why I was trying to include "*server*"

Comment: I also have tried this but am getting an error =IFS(AND(B2,{"*server*"},C2,">0"),"Attention","")

Comment: No sorry, I think it would if B was a match of "server' but it needs to be contains "server' like i said B can have "Windows Server 2012" "Windows Server 2003" etc.

Comment: I changed it to use SEARCH, which now returns true when the string contains `Server`.  Are you using the one with search?

Comment: Woohooo that one did it!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Place your data in an Excel Table using Ctrl + T or from the Insert Tab, click on Table and create your table. Then you can reference columns and rows in your table. Also, you will avoid replicating your function in the entire sheet column.

Then create your function

```
    =
IF (
    AND ( NOT ( ISERROR ( SEARCH ( "server", [@OS] ) ) ), [@DaysOffline] > 0 ),
    "Attention",
    ""
)
```

Each time you will add data to your table the calculated column will automatically extend the function to the new record.